Mechanism of random assortment of chromosomes
How does the random assortment of chromosomes during meiosis occur?
I am a mathematician, not a biologist, and I am surprised that it is difficult to find an answer to this question online (AI chatbots are also clueless). If I were human or a computer, I would use a random generator (coin flips, dice, pretty sophisticated algorithms in the case of a computer) to perform the random assortment.
How does this work during meiosis? What random generator mechanics are being used? It is not sufficient to say the assortment is random. Randomness needs to be accomplished by a mechanism.

We don't post duplicates on purpose, and we close them when we find them. If there's something you didn't understand about the answer posted there, could you either leave a comment on the answer  to see if the author can help - or you can post a bounty on the question so it receives more attention. You'll be able to place bounties on things when you've sufficient reputation. Alternatively, you could [edit] to clarify how this is different from that one.

Would you consider https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion to be a "mechanism"? That's generally what one means when talking about randomness in chemical reactions. It's a bit weird to ask what the mechanism of randomness should be; in most of the physical world, randomness is the "null hypothesis", and the interesting stuff is that which happens not-completely-randomly. So, biologists would study why there are "hot spots" or places where recombination is more common than elsewhere, rather than why it doesn't always happen in the same exact place.

Randomness is hard in computing; it's not hard in the real world.

Quite true, computers generate pseudo-random numbers, the more sophisticated the algorithms, the more random. Electronic engineers use thermodynamics and the behavior of individual electrons in "hot" components to generate actual random numbers.

Does this answer your question? How random is genetic recombination?

@John, that question is about recombination. This question is about assortment, which is a distinct (though procedurally related) process. Recombination is about how recombinant segments form chromosomes, assortment is about how chromosomes end up in gametes.

@JiminyCricket I would argue that this is a distinct question (see comment to John). Independent assortment and recombination are distinct processes.

@MaximilianPress vote to close retracted, your problem is indepentant assortment can refer to both.  I would assume a mechanism would be needed to prevent random assortment of chrmosomes, since chromosomes are not grouped or organized by cells.

OK, @MaximilianPress I'll abide - not being overly familiar with the topic I'll not flag.

keep in mind mathmatically random and scientifically random do not mean the same thing. a mutation is random even if we know all the causes and can predict them. Random is often synonimous with sufficently random to be difficult to predict in biology.

@John: understood, I think of recombination as specifically the process by which crossovers occur chromosomes and of independent assortment as specifically the mechanism by which individual alleles/chromosomes are inherited (e.g. here), but I guess all of these concepts get fuzzy, especially from person to person. When I get some time I will try to edit the question to carve out the two concepts and also try to answer.

Welcome to SE Biology. Our subject may lack mathematical precision, but we try to use precise and complete descriptions when we are communicating our ideas. You will notice I have edited your original question to make it clear you are talking about chromosomes, and maintained the words “random” and “assortment” rather than indulging in the “elegant variation” of “independent” and “segregation”, which is confusing to the non-expert who  cannot be sure you are referring to the same thing. I also stated your title with a capital letter — we like to maintain standards on our site.

God does play dice! And I am not aware that he needs to invoke his powers to ensure that there is a one-in-six chance of throwing a six.
So I don’t accept the unsubstantiated assertion in the question. Is there a mechanism to determine which atom of radioactive carbon-14 in a population is the one that decays? And radioactive decay — a zeroth order process — is surely random.

David, I think the question poster would consider carbon-14 decay to be a mechanism, and thus be the answer he is seeking (although probably desiring further explanation about how radioactive decay controls the selection).  The fact that our understanding of that quantum process indicates it is not predictable would not be relevant to its being a 'mechanism'.  I presume you don't believe it is in fact based on decay but rather believe it is based on the thermodynamic unpredictability of ...

(Cont'd)... molecular motions in the cellular environment.  I suppose you jumped to a quantum mechanism rather than the actual thermodynamic one is for rhetorical impact since the thermodynamics are predictable in theory (though not in practice), while quantum theory indicates it is simply not predictable.  Since the poster considers coin flipping a mechanism (though "theoretically predictable"), he should also consider thermodynamic disorder a mechanism.

@mgkrebbs — I had considered discussing this. I would consider throwing dice the end as well as (or rather than) the "mechanism" the poster invokes. Likewise for chromosome segregation. And, though not qualified to say more, I assume randomness in nature is a fundamental consequence of the physics of matter. I would say that randomness needs no justification — it is non-randomness that does. Were the dice loaded?
